# Design strategy to save in the background with MagicalRecord

Tags: cocoa, core-data, concurrency, magicalrecord

Recently I started a new app requiring just one store (no document based app). For some time I was quite happy thinking I could finally get rid of throwing around the NSManagedObjectContext... until I wanted to save in the background :-(

Now I am confused about my own code. For example:

```
- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];
    [self resetCard];
    self.creationDate = TODAY;
    self.dictionary = [Dictionary activeDictionary];
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center postNotificationName:NOTE_NEWCARD object:self];    
}
```

[Dictionary activeDictionary] is a NSManagedObject static function returning a pointer to a NSManagedObject created in the main thread. That will cause a cross/context error during the background save. Because my program always read from the same store, I thought I could avoid writing this:

```
[Dictionary activeDictionaryWithContext:...]
```

I suppose that with MagicalRecord, as long as I work always with the same backend is is possible to avoid passing the context pointer. Which function should I use to get that context?

```
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]
```

In the example the object sends itself within a notification, something almost granted to cause more conflicts.

- In the case of the notification should I always send only the objectID?

It seems to me that my objects should issue side effect operations/notifications only if they are running in the main context. However some of those side operations change my object graph creating new instances of other entities.

- Can I safely omit the two problematic function calls I have mentioned if I save with  [MagicalRecord MR_saveAll] ?
- Should I assume that the objects of the new background saving context will be an exact copy of the ones in my main thread without calling those extra functions?

Now I am having problems because I never expected awakeFromInsert to run several times for the same object of the same store. I was thinking about something like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];
    if ([self managedObjectContext] == [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]) {
        [self resetCard];
        self.creationDate = TODAY;
        self.dictionary = [Dictionary activeDictionary];
        NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center postNotificationName:NOTE_NEWCARD object:self];    
    }
}
```

That should make my awakeFromInsert code run only once, but not in the background saving context. I am concerned about losing information if I do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can certainly send your object in a notification that way, I would recommend **against** that. Remember, even with the new parent-child contexts in CoreData, NSManagedObjects are **NOT** thread safe. If you create or import objects, you will need to save them prior to using them in another context.

MagicalRecord provides a relatively simple API for background saving:

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    MyEntity *newEntity = [MyEntity MR_createInContext:localContext];

    //perform other entity operations here
}];
```

This block does all the work for you, without worrying about setting up the NSManagedObjectContext properly.

Another reason you should not pass NSManagedObjects across a notification is that you do not know what thread the notification will be received on. This can potentially lead to a crash, because, again, NSManagedObjects are **NOT** thread safe.

Another alternative to the notification approach you present is to add an observer to **NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification**, and merge your changes on that notification. This will fire only after your objects are saved, and are safe for crossing contexts through either the parent-child relationship, or the persistent store (the old way).

Comment: Thanks, I am using MagicalRecord 2.0.7 and although I only work with one context, the plain MR_save is giving some trouble because it works with a second context it created. Worst of all, the notification came from a third context ?!?!?

Comment: I know that NSManagedObjects are not thread safe, my problem is how I should deal with that and what happens during MR_save. I see a second context being created, therefore my awakeFromInsert is being called twice for objects of the same store. I am concerned about losing information if  my awakeFromInsert code runs only if the current context is the main thread. Updating question now...

Comment: awakeFromInsert is being called twice because you are creating two instances on separate contexts. I think what you want is to create the object, then save, then load the object in a second context.

Comment: Two days after this post I found out that I must write the condition to exclude the awakeFromInsert if not running in the current context. I am quite sure I only work with one single context. MR_save does create a new one and re-create instances of all my objects, therefore executing twice all my awakeFromInsert. Using the standard :save:&error does not trigger the second call.

Comment: Is the context merging handled by Magic? Or do I need setup stuff the AppDelegate to handle this?